# Get column names in sub-query

Tags: sql, subquery

I know that I can do this to get the column names from some table:

```
SELECT 
COLUMN_NAME
FROM ALL_TAB_COLS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'MY_TABLE'
```

But what if I want to do something like this (bit of pseudo code):

```
WITH
    SUB1 AS (SELECT COLUMN_1, COLUMN_2 FROM SOME_TABLE1)
    SUB2 AS (SELECT COLUMN_1, COLUMN_2 FROM SOME_TABLE2)
    RESULTS AS
    (SELECT COLUMN_NAME
     FROM SUB1
     INNER JOIN SUB2 ON SUB1.COLUMN_NAME = SUB2.COLUMN_NAME)

SELECT * FROM RESULTS
```

Is something like this possible?

Comment: Let's just say that I need an easy way to compare tables with the same column names.

Comment: you can do that with a normal query. just alias the names.   table1.col_a as A , table2.col_a as A_1

Comment: Sorry, I know what you mean, I just didn't express myself properly. I need to compare the column names of a table with an external list of column names which I dont have a table for and I cannot have a table for.

Comment: use sys.columns to query the column names for your tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can query information_schema.COLUMNS to get the column names and compare them across tables.

```
Select distinct column_name, table_name 
from information_schema.COLUMNS 
where table_name in('table1','table2') 
and column_name = 'column_name'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have an external list of column name to compare with table column name

i suggest i where in clause

```
 SELECT 
 COLUMN_NAME
 FROM ALL_TAB_COLS
 WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'MY_TABLE'
 AND COLUMN_NAME in ('colname1,' 'colname2' .... )
```

or use not in for the inverse

Answer (score 0):

The solution I was looking for when landing on this page is called a "column subquery". I hope this helps..,

SELECT t1.column1, t1.column2, t2.column1, t2.column2

FROM some_table1 AS t1

INNER JOIN some_table2 AS t2

ON t1.column1 = t2.column1

WHERE t2.column1 = "column1";

I was stuck on this and found my solution here:

https://www.geeksengine.com/database/subquery/return-a-list-of-values.php